# jQuery If statement work only on Firefox

Tags: php, jquery, google-chrome, if-statement

I have sth like this

```
<?php 
if($target == 'mailAvailability'){
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $query = 'SELECT email from users WHERE email = "'. $email . '"';
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
            echo 0;
        } else {
            echo 1;
            }
    }
?>
```

and code in jquery

```
$.post("downloadData.php",{target: "mailAvailability", email:email},function(dane){
                            if(dane == 0){
                            $('#formError').html("Mail jest zajęty");
                            } else {
                                $('#formError').html(dane);
                            }

                        });
```

but in this code if statement doesn't work in chrome and IE. In firefox it works correctly. Why?

Comment: console log dane in IE and chrome and see what it returns ? Or alternatively use a json object to pass back the status which i find more suitable for this stuff.

Comment: *How* does it not work? What did you expect and what happened instead?

Comment: As @Lee said, what happens when you do `console.log(dane)` in the JS?

Comment: It shows 0 or 1. Even if I make `parseInt(dane)` it still does not work.

Comment: And theres definately no whitespace being returned? 

what if you use $.trim(dane) or even 

if(dane.match(/\d+/)[1] == 0) {  }

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the right syntax for your post options: {"target":"mailAvailability","email":"email"}

Pay attention to the second option email.
If it is a string, put it as stated before.
If it is a javascript variable, just put email.
If it is the PHP variable as in the PHP-code, use `"<?php echo $email; ?>"`.

IE breaks on every error it finds.

Hope this helped you out.

Comment: I defined email earlier: var email = $('#email').val();
I did what You say but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: dane is the output of what did "downloadData.php"